# Debian sudo su still asks for password - but does not accept nor needs the password

Tags: sudo

I have searched a lot but never found this behaviour:

When I enter "sudo su" I am asked for the password. But when I enter the password, I am asked another time. 3 times regulary, 3 times as a host user. I can even type CTRL+d 6 times. I am always asked again and in the end I am root.

```
myuser@myserver:~ $ sudo su
Password authentication
Password:
Password authentication
Password:
Password authentication
Password:
myuser@localhost's password:
Permission denied, please try again.
myuser@localhost's password:
Permission denied, please try again.
myuser@localhost's password:
myuser@localhost: Permission denied, please try again. (keyboard-interactive,password,publickkey).
root@myserver:/home/myuser# whoami
root
```

As I said, it does not change anything on the output if I enter the corect password, the wrong password or CTRL+D on any password request.

Entry of sudoers (edited with visudo):

```
#
# This file MUST be edited with the 'visudo' command as root.
#
# Please consider adding local content in /etc/sudoers.d/ instead of
# directly modifying this file.
#
# See the man page for details on how to write a sudoers file.
#
Defaults        env_reset
Defaults        mail_badpass
Defaults        secure_path="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin"

# Host alias specification

# User alias specification

# Cmnd alias specification

# User privilege specification
root    ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

# Allow members of group sudo to execute any command
%sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

# See sudoers(5) for more information on "#include" directives:

#includedir /etc/sudoers.d

myuser ALL=(ALL:ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL
```

I am a member of the sudo group:

```
cat /etc/group | grep sudo
sudo:x:27:myuser
```

It worked perfectly for years and I can only imagine two possible incidents (But as I didn't use sudo su before or later those incidents for a long time, I am not even sure if there is a connection):

1. apt-get upgrade
2. Maybe a Power loss

Any guess what to check?

Comment: Does `sudo -s` show similar behaviour?

Comment: Thanks for the quick help. Yes, exactly the same.

Comment: Running `sudo su` is pointless.  if you want an interactive root shell, just run `sudo -i`. Your `/etc/sudoers` is configured to allow`myuser` and members of group `sudo` to run anything.

Comment: I need it for scripts. But nevertheless, this behaviour of sudo su is wrong. (I have erased a previous post, but that was a wrong lead) I need the sudo command without password promt.

Comment: No, you don't need `sudo su` for scripts.  Just `sudo` alone will do. `sudo -u user` if you need to run something as a specific user.  `sudo -i` or `sudo -s` if you want an interactive shell (depending on whether you want a login or non-login shell).  `sudo su` is **never** needed for anything.  It's just a bad habit that somebody clueless started a few decades ago and has been cargo-culted by people who just blindly copy and paste stuff they don't understand ever since.

Comment: Yes, you are right for the script. But still, `sudo -i` and `sudo -s` are asking 6 times for a password and than still let me be root if all 6 are wrong. Something turned bad with sudo and as far as I dont know what, I can not trust sudoers to protect my system, if the configuration rules are not working as set. Just stopping using it, is not fixing anything. Can you please help me. Any hint or guess? I would dig as deep as I can, but I have no clue in which direction.

Comment: Use `sudo -l -l` to list what sudo thinks matches you (in particular expect `Options: !authenticate`). Check there are no files in `/etc/sudoers.d/`. Check if files have been changed in `/etc/pam.d/` including `/etc/pam.d/sudo` `/etc/pam.d/sudo-i`

Comment: Luckly I have found a backup of the whole disk from 2 weeks ago. And two Rapsberrys. Unfortunatelly `sudo -l -l`, `ls /etc/sudoers.d/ -la` and `ls /etc/pam.d/ -la` have the exact same output on both disks/Rapsberrys. I will find some time and make a `diff` of both disks. I will reach out to you when I find the difference. But so long, thank you so much for trying to help me.